# jQuery - Easyslider Internet Explorer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, slider, easyslider

I have built a website but really struggling with easyslider and Internet explorer. It seems the Javascript is loading and then deciding against it for some reason.

jQuery is included in the header then we have this for the slider it's self.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider({
        auto: true, 
        continuous: true,
        speed: 700,
        pause:  3000,
        controlsShow: true,
        numeric: true,
        numericId: 'controls'
    });
}); 
</script>
<div id="slider">
<ul>
<?php 
$slider = "SELECT * FROM slider WHERE active='1' ORDER BY name DESC";
$result = mysql_query($slider,$con) or die('Error, query failed' . mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<li><a href="' . $row['url'] . '"><img src="' . $row['image'] . '" alt="' . $row['name'] . '" /></li>';
            }
            ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

The issue is that IE9 seems to double the number of slides.

Then IE 7/8 just don't show the slides or the controls at all...

Works fine in webkit/firefox/IE10

Any ideas at all? Really stumped on this one.

Live site to test: http://lucidcreations.co.uk/idealboat/index2.php (Stripped of the rest of homepage content)

Comment: I just visited the site, and the slider seems to be working great on IE7 and 8 ... with dots, and continous slide...

Comment: Well... That's confused me widely? Any chance of being cheeky and asking of a screenshot from you? Apparently my virtual machines aren't doing their jobs right :s

Comment: Not that Im running all those versions of IE, but if you go to internet explorer 10, press F12, there is a button in the top that says: Explorer Mode, there you can switch to IE7 and IE8 mode... that is how I tested it, your code seems correct to me...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
After trying to validate your link it appears that there are quite a few syntax errors and warnings. Given the sensitivity of internet explorer, it  might be worthwhile to pick off as much low hanging fruit as you can then test again. **One I'd imagine could really be a barrier is adding the script type to your jquery and slider libraries.** They simply could not be loading correctly as a result of incorrect interpretation.

**Here is the validation:** http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flucidcreations.co.uk%2Fidealboat%2Findex2.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Unfortunately IE simulation mode does not act in quite the same way as it would in a virtual machine. Nicholas-c likely is seeing the results that most would see, as that is how an IE user would be seeing the site.

I'm getting many non-descript errors from IE 7 and 8 (Dialog boxes that simply say "Error: 153 unknown or the like) but also 404 error when looking for a specific jQuery library called **http://lucidcreations.co.uk/idealboat/js/jquery-1.10.0.min.map** in Chrome dev tools.

I suggest trying a jQuery library switch out for either the latest latest version or maybe an older version that perhaps has more IE testing done, and perhaps also check the browser support for the slider library.

I do notice that there is some inline jQuery in your index2.php that could be optimized to reduce the on the fly dom parsing that may have an effect on performance but probably not enough to prevent loading in older IE versions.